# Whats the best way to find out if an Object is an Array

Tags: javascript

As far as I know there are three ways of finding out if an object is an Array

by `isArray` function if implemented

```
Array.isArray()
```

by `toString`

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply( obj ) === "[object Array]"
```

and by `instanceof`

```
obj instanceof Array
```

Is there any reason to choose one over the other?

Comment: The second one is easier to read, all else equal, that's enough for me to say it is better.

Comment: I forgot about `Array.isObject`, thanks @arnaud

Comment: Object.prototype.toString.apply( obj ) === "[object Array]" is the one that will return true if the array was created in another window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is probably to use the standard [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), if it's implemented by the engine:

```
isArray = Array.isArray(myObject)
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Compatibility) recommends to use the `toString()` method when `Array.isArray` isn't implemented:

> #### Compatibility
>
> Running the following code before any other code will create
>   Array.isArray if it's not natively available. This relies on
>   Object.prototype.toString being unchanged and call resolving to the
>   native Function.prototype.call method.
>
> ```
> if(!Array.isArray) {  
>   Array.isArray = function (arg) {  
>     return Object.prototype.toString.call(arg) == '[object Array]';  
>   };  
> }
> ```

Both jQuery and [underscore.js<sup>*[source]*</sup>](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/blob/39b07d7b2cdbcf2f37b1239772ba58617f7c3650/underscore.js#L654) take the `toString() === "[object Array]"` way.

Comment: wouldn't you get a null exception on the Array.isArray if is was null? this means you would need a null check first.

Comment: Actually `Array.isArray()` is not an instance method that you call like Array.isArray(theObject). I mistakenly wrote `Object.isArray`, fixed, thanks

Comment: In your first bullet point, are you saying that you can use `Array.isArray()` to detect an "array-like" object? *"They are a fast way to ask the object if it quacks like an array."*

Comment: yeah, I just removed this, it was wrong since isArray is a *static* method of Array.

Comment: Ok, good. `Array.isArray` it's defined by the spec as basically a wrapper for the `Object.prototype.toString` test (testing the internal [[Class]] property).

Answer (score 1):

Unless it was proven that the former has significant performance benefits and my app required every last ounce of speed I would go for the latter.

The reason is readability, pure and simple.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is to decide whether a parameter passed to you is an array that you should iterate over, there's a fair amount of code out there that just looks for a `.length` attribute and treats as an array or a pseudo-array if that attribute is present.

This is because there are lots of things that aren't actually arrays (but are pseudo arrays with array like capabilities) that you may want your code to treat like an array.  Examples of some of these kinds of things are a jQuery object or a nodeList returned from many DOM calls. Here's a code example:

```
// accepts:
//    single DOM element
//    array of DOM elements
//    nodeList as returned from various DOM functions like getElementsByClassName
//    any array like object with a .length attribute and items in numeric indexes from 0 to .length-1 like a jQuery object
function hideElements(input) {
    if (input.length !== undefined) {
        for (var i = 0, len = input.length; i < len; i++) {
            input[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    } else {
        input.style.display = "none";
    }
    return(input);
}
```

The jQuery `.each()` function also just tests the parameter passed to it for .length (and verifying that it's not a function) before deciding it's something it should iterate like an array.

If that isn't the problem you're trying to solve, I can find two references to using the first technique:

1. jQuery's implementation of isArray uses the first technique.
2. MDN (Mozilla Developer Network) recommends the first one [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray).

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` tests whether the given constructor (Array) is in the object's prototype chain, while your second approach only checks the actual type of the object.  In other words, if your object inherits from Array, the second test will be true, but the first will be false.  Now, it's not typically done to inherit from Array (it doesn't work right in IE), but walking the prototype chain presumably adds some overhead (especially if the object isn't an array).