# Optimal way of determining array type

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to determining the object type is Array and why?.

```
var arr = [];

// Method #1
Array.isArray(arr);

// Method #2 
toString.call(arr) == "[object Array]"

// Method #3
arr.constructor == Array
```

Comment: It seems obvious to me that the best way would be to use the function built exactly for that purpose - namely `Array.isArray`. I can't see how either of the other ways could be better but maybe someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: FWIW, these all correctly yield `false` on the special  `arguments` object defined inside a function.

Comment: Or, the literal duplicate: [Whats the best way to find out if an Object is an Array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7447425/1048572)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three methods can be used to test if variable is of Array type. However, there are some nuances. I will start from the last to first.

**Method #3.** Will not work if variable in question came from other winndow/frame. In this case, constructor will point the the different `Array` object and this check will return `false`. For the same reason, `arr instanceof Array` is not bullet-proof. So it's not 100% reliable.

**Method #2**. This is the method that has been traditionally used to verify array type. In fact, `Array.isArray` [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Polyfill) is based on this method. The only disadvantage is that it's cumbersome and verbose.

**Method #1**. Is the one from ES5 that should finally be used to test array type, no matter what realm array comes from (like iframe). This is is the best in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The prefered method is to use `Array.isArray`. This is present in the ES5 language specification and quite well supported by the browsers.

If you plan to support old browsers, You can find a polyfill on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). The polyfill is basically your second option.

The last option will not work if you play with iframes.

```
var arr = myIframe.contentWindow.myArray;
console.log(obj.constructor === Array); //false
```

The reason is that the `Array` constructor is diffferent for each `window` object. Using this to detect arrays will work 99% of the time but will suddenly fail one day.